# how can i create shortcodes for include a page in blade

Tags: laravel, shortcode

I want to create shortcodes system for my Laravel project to include a page in another page.

Anyone have a solution?

```
[include]test[/include]  ->   @include('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

[This package](https://github.com/patrickbrouwers/Laravel-Shortcodes) is probably what you're wanting.

Something like:

```
class IncludeShortcode {

  public function register($shortcode, $content, $compiler, $name)
  {
    return view($content);
  }
}

Shortcode::register('include', 'IncludeShortcode');
```

Not tested, but should get you going in the right direction.